# How to output html through AngularJS template?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, angularjs, view

```
<h1>{{ revision.title }}</h1>

<div ng-bind-html="revision.content"></div>
```

The title outputs fine, but the content - doesn't. It's got some html in it and I get the following error: `Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.` which is being described as so: http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce:unsafe and that's fine, but then how can I output the content as there will be some html in it and so I must set it to `{{ revision.content | safe }}` or smthn. What is the correct way?

EDIT:

AngularJS version: 1.2

Answer (score 110, accepted):

So the fix is this:

include `angular-sanitize.min.js` from http://code.angularjs.org/ and include it in your module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

and then you're free to use `ng-bind-html`

Comment: 2 years later in 1.4.x, this deceptively simple fix still works!

Comment: It fixed my problem, when I used **$compile**

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an older question, but you can also trust the value using `$sce` in your controller:

```
$scope.revision.content = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.revision.content);
```

After that, `ng-bind-html` will work.

Answer (score 3):

I created an `ng-html` directive that does the same basic thing that `ng-bind-html-unsafe` used to do.  However, I strongly suggest that you only use it with caution.  It could easily open your site up to malicious attacks. So know what you're doing before you implement it:

```
.directive('ngHtml', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        if(attrs.ngHtml){
            elem.html(scope.$eval(attrs.ngHtml));
            $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngHtml, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
                elem.html(newValue);
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

And then you would use it as:

```
<div ng-html="revision.content"></div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the directive, works great! just the last line is missing a closing ] - should be `}]);`

Answer (score 2):

What version are you using?
If you are using less than 1.2 you can try `ngBindHtmlUnsafe`

Answer (score 0):

according to [Official AngularJs Doc about `ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) you must inject ngSanitize into your app dependencies

> Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the
>   element in a secure way. By default, the resulting HTML content will
>   be sanitized using the $sanitize service. To utilize this
>   functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by
>   including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core
>   Angular). In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies,
>   you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application.

Then you can install `ngSanitize` module by there ways:

1 - using **bower**

```
bower install --save angular-sanitize
```

2 - using **npm**

```
npm install --save angular-sanitize
```

3 - manually by download `angular-sanitize.js` file from [code.angularjs.org path which include all angularJs files categories by version number](http://code.angularjs.org/) like [@Xeen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19770567/1908296)

See More about install `ngSanitize` module from [Oficial angularJs github repository for install  angular-sanitize](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize)