# ng-show along with ng-bind-html in an isolated scope - directive is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-show

I have referred to the previously asked question here -> [same kind of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412126/angular-ng-show-ng-hide-not-working-correctly-with-ng-bind-html)

but the answers did not help.

This is my master HTML:

```
<!--ss.com header starts here-->
       <ss-header show="showHeader"></ss-header>
<!--ss.com header ends here-->
```

The {{headerHTML}} doesn't show the HTML in the template below:

This is my directive template - ss_header.html:

```
<header data-ng-show="{{show}}">
    <div class="ss-header" data-ng-bind-html="headerHTML|convertAsHtml"></div>

</header>{{headerHTML}}

<div data-ng-show="{{show}}">Sample text to show ng-show is working properly in this directive.</div>
```

This is my directive.js

```
smartPrintApp.directive("ssHeader", ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "E", //directive for element only 
    //replace: true, //replace the custom tag
    scope:{
        show:'=show'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             scope.$watch(attrs.unsecureBind, function(newval) {
                  element.html(newval);
                  $compile(element.contents())(scope);
             });
    },  
    templateUrl: 'common/header/ss_header.html',
  }
}]);
```

And this is my controller:

```
var smartPrintApp = angular.module("smartPrintApp",['ngRoute','ngResource','ngCookies', 'ngAria', 'ngAnimate']);

smartPrintApp.filter("convertAsHtml", ['$sce', function($sce){ return $sce.trustAsHtml}]);

smartPrintApp.controller("dotComController",['$scope', '$resource', 'serviceInfo', 'fetchLocalData', 'fetchServiceData', '$sce', '$window', '$http',   '$compile', '$interpolate', function($scope, $resource, $service, fetchLocalData, fetchServiceData, $sce, $window, $http, $compile, $interpolate) {

    /* Get Data from Server */
    var reqData = {
        "key1":"value1",//variables to send if needed
        "key2":"value2"//variables to send if needed
    };
    var generalServ = new fetchServiceData($service.api.SERV_RESP);

    generalServ.save(reqData).$promise.then(function(response){

        /* Site Layout Modifications */
        $scope.headerHTML = $interpolate(response.siteLayout.headerHtmlContent)($scope);
        $scope.showHeader = response.siteLayout.headerEnabled;
        /* Site Layout Modifications */

    },function(err){
        console.log('error in fetching service data')
    });
    /* Get Data from Server */
}]);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In you directive `restrict`  is give `element` but in your html this is `class`. So please change it...

Comment: @vamsikrishnamannem, sorry for not adding the master HTML template. That's a different html from where this directive is being called. Please check now.

Comment: remove expression braces from `ng-show`

Comment: Use `data-ng-show="show"` You don't need string interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't show because you're using isolated scope but haven't passed in the header html. So currently `{{headerHTML}}` in your directive template is undefined. Change your isolated scope to:

```
scope:{
    show:'=show',
    headerHTML: '=header'
},
```

And your HTML to:

```
<ss-header show="showHeader" header="headerHTML"></ss-header>
```

Comment: yes! that worked! Previously I was binding my html without creating an isolated scope in my directive and hence my binding worked. But, when I created isolated scope, I should have obviously passed my scope variable in my html. You saved my day!