# Using ng-bind-html and $sce.trustAsHtml create a string with ng-model binding

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I want to create dynamically forms. Inside my controller i create a string

```
var str = "<input type='text' value='" + $scope.selectedData.code + "' class='form-control' />";
$scope.htmlString = $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
```

and in my html page

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlString"></div>
```

i get the value but is not binding.
I try also with

```
var str = "<input type='text' ng-model='" + $scope.selectedData.code + "' class='form-control' />";
$scope.htmlString = $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
```

also doesn't work. Can anyone know how can this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML :

Add a directive: `compile-template`

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlString" compile-template></div>
```

JS :

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('controller1', ['$scope','$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    var str = "<input type='text' ng-model='" + $scope.selectedData.code + "' class='form-control' />";
    $scope.htmlString = $sce.trustAsHtml(str);
}])
.directive('compileTemplate', function($compile, $parse){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var parsed = $parse(attr.ngBindHtml);
            function getStringValue() {
                return (parsed(scope) || '').toString();
            }

            // Recompile if the template changes
            scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
                $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  // The -9999 makes it skip directives so that we do not recompile ourselves
            });
        }
    }
});
```