# trustAshtml doesnt work after filter array and remove some indexes

Tags: angularjs

I push some data contain trustAshtml in an array like this code below

```
eachTask = {
        'name':el.name,
        'taskTitle':$sce.trustAsHtml(el.desc),
        'task_type':el.task_type,
}

all_tasks.push(eachTask);
```

when I filter this array and splice it ,
I get this error after filtering

```
Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.
```

I use `ng-bind-html`, for the first time doesn't appear any error and code works fine but after remove some index of array this error appear.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770156/how-to-output-html-through-angularjs-template

Answer (score 1):

Include `ngSanitize` to your modules:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```