# Angular filter for HTML formatting

Tags: angularjs, html

Is there an existing angular filter for making JSON data appear as formatted HTML?

JSON data from a controller:

```
{ data: 'This data is <b>bold</b>' }
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{data | someKindOfFormatFilter }}</div>
```

Wanted result:

This data is **bold**

Comment: you want to bind HTML with filter right?

Comment: Use ``ng-bind-html``  like ``<div ng-bind-html='data'></div>``

Comment: you can use ng-style and ng-class directive

Comment: @SameerK ng-bind-html gives me an error: Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.

Comment: @Yaseminçidem The styling will come from the data. I don't know what the styling will be. Only that it is safe and only contains <u>, <b> or <i> + <span style=''> elements.

Comment: Take a look at the last 2 answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770156/how-to-output-html-through-angularjs-template to fix the issue.

Comment: @SameerK Yes. That works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing as SameerK suggested, to use `ngSanitize` and `ng-bind-html`

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Answered in this post:
[How to output html through AngularJS template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770156/how-to-output-html-through-angularjs-template)